# How to switch to Inverse Kinematic for Make Human model in blender 2.78?

Tags: makehuman, inverse-kinematics

I exported a human in mhx2 format from MakeHuman and imported it to Blender 2.78a. **What is necessary to install in blender in order to see the MHX Main panel and/or switch from FK to IK mode for posing the model?** I am rather new to Blender and I've no clue what else to do.

So far I installed and enabled addons from `community-extras-blenderplugins-v1.1.0-cr1.zip` found from MakeHuman download [page](http://download.tuxfamily.org/makehuman/releases/1.1.0/) (containing total of 4 addons: mhx2 Import, Make Clothes, Make Target and Make Walk, also tried install from `blendertools-1.1.0-all.zip` containing the same). But in both cases I cannot see anything like on this screenshot (from a [YT tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eThtuXZZ7M0), which I believe is the way to switch to IK):

[image]

Instead, in my Tools panel, there is MHX2 palette and MakeWalk palette, and in Properties panel I have Make Clothes and Make Target, but nothing similar to the above screenshot. Here is what I have in blender in all panels:

[image]

So the only thing referring to IK is in the Make Walk panel. After checking the Inverse Kinematics and then Transfer FK => IK (no idea if this is what I need to do, just guessing) I get an error:

[image]

The [url](http://www.makehuman.org/doc/node/makewalk_errors_and_corrective_actions) with corrective actions returns page not found.

To sum up, I am looking for a way to be able to drag a bone near the wrist of my Make Human model and see the whole arm move (this is inverse kinematic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check "Override Exported Data" when importing the mhx2 file, and add a rig:

[image]

The rig controls are under the "MHX2 Runtime" tab (Layers and "FK/IK Switch") in the tools panel. The MakeWalk addon is not needed for this, only the MakeHuman import-runtime.